# Most Efficient way to sum rgb values with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a working program, although working may be an overstatement. I want to optimize my code, I am using a for loop to sum the red, green, and blue pixel value for the screen.

I have previously tried summing along the second axis but to no avail. So any other tips would help. I am also down to use different libraries if necessary.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

colors = ['red', 'lime', 'blue']
explode = (0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
labels = ['Red', 'Green', 'Blue']
nums = [0, 0, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def update(num):
    ax.clear()
    ax.axis('equal')
    str_num = str(num)

    nums = [0, 0, 0]

    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1080)))
    for x in range ((1079)):
        for y in range ((1919)):
            nums[0] += screen[x][y][0]
            nums[1] += screen[x][y][1]
            nums[2] += screen[x][y][2]

    ax.pie(nums, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
    ax.set_title(str_num)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

I expect to have at least a slight improvement in my time. Currently, it takes around 7 or 8 seconds to load a new frame, but I would be happy with anything under 3 to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a for loop since your `screen` variable is a NumPy array. You can directly do the sum as

```
def update(num):
    ax.clear()
    ax.axis('equal')
    str_num = str(num)

    nums = [0, 0, 0]
    screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,0,1920,1080)))
    # This should work too:
    # nums = np.sum(screen, axis=(1,2))
    nums[0] = np.sum(screen[:,:,0])
    nums[1] = np.sum(screen[:,:,1])
    nums[2] = np.sum(screen[:,:,2])

    ax.pie(nums, explode=explode, labels=labels, colors=colors,
            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
    ax.set_title(str_num)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works extremely well. My problem before was that I was attempting to sum the RGB value with [:][:][0] instead of [:,:,0]. Good answer and very fast response.

Comment: apparently, you can pass a tuple to `np.sum`, e.g.  `nums = np.sum(screen, axis=(0,1))` might save a bit more.  then again matplotlib is so slow that you probably won't notice it